# What is ' print() ' doing with this code? How is it working even though nothing is inside the brackets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def nested(n):
   for j in range(n):
       for i in range(n):
           print(i, end=' ')
       print()
```

When i tried omitting print(), the output was: line1>>>0 1 0 1 instead of line1>>0 1 then line2>>0 1 , but i'm not understanding how this print function having nothing inside its brackets is resulting in that difference in the output...

Comment: Unless you have a future import, this is not the case in Python 2: it will print an empty tuple.

Answer (score 2):

`print()` by default prints a `line feed` (a new line)

Answer (score 0):

So in this case the indentations mean everything. the print() just prints a new line. In your code the inner loop completes then a new line gets printed.

Comment: Thank you cody! say hello to zack.

Answer (score 0):

`print(*args)` prints out its arguments and then an ending. It does the same thing if no arguments are present.

By default the ending part is a newline, but in your example one line overrides it by using `end=' '`

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent definition of the print function is:

```
import sys

def print(*objects, sep=None, end=None, file=None, flush=False):
    """A Python translation of the C code for builtins.print()."""
    if sep is None:
        sep = ' '
    if end is None:
        end = '\n'
    if file is None:
        file = sys.stdout
    file.write(sep.join(map(str, objects)) + end)
    if flush:
        file.flush()
```

[Here(Why `print` became a function in Python 3) you can have a detailed read about print()](http://www.snarky.ca/why-print-became-a-function-in-python-3)